# WebAdministration provider is not available on Windows Server 2016

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

Here is a puzzling issue.  On some Windows Servers in my organization, if I try to run `Get-WebSite` in PowerShell, I get the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\me> Get-Website
Attempting to perform the Start operation on the 'WebAdministration' provider failed. Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
Get-Website : Cannot find a provider with the name 'WebAdministration'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Website
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (WebAdministration:String) [Get-Website], ProviderNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderNotFound,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.GetWebsiteCommand
```

This works fine other other Windows Servers.  So far, I've tested successfully on some Server 2012 and 2019.

Here is what I've checked:

1. Yes. I am running Powershell as Administrator
2. `Get-PSProvider` does NOT output an entry for `WebAdministration .. .{IIS}`
3. Ensured the following features are installed: Web-Mgmt-Service, Web-Mgmt-Console, Web-Scripting-Tools, Web-Asp-Net45
4. `Get-Module WebAdministration -ListAvailable`: outputs 1.0.0.0 WebAdministration`
5. `Get-Module WebAdministration -Listavailable | Select-Object -Property Path`

   ```
   # output
   C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\WebAdministartion.psd1
   ```

At this point, I am not sure what else to try but am wondering if there's a particular bug related to Server 2016 and a GPO or enterprise antimalware service.

Any tips on troubleshooting the provider?